# Custom Implicit Writes for java.util.Date

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

I am trying to create a custom implicit `Writes` for `java.util.Date`. The default behavior is serializing the `Date` object into the time in milliseconds.  I want to serialize the `Date` into a string in a simple `yyyy-MM-dd` format. I have tried the following two snippets of code to no avail.

```
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
implicit object dateWrites extends Writes[java.util.Date] {
  def writes(date: java.util.Date): JsValue = {
    JsString(formatter.format(date))
  }
}
```

and also

```
implicit val dateWrites: Writes[java.util.Date] = new Writes[java.util.Date] {
  override def writes(date: java.util.Date): JsValue = {
    JsString(formatter.format(date))
  }
}
```

Comment: What failure are you getting - is it compiling this code or is it not being picked up in the code that utilizes it?

Comment: Both versions are working for me here. Can you paste code that uses the Writes? Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I'm finding out that the placement of the implicit Writes[Date] is very important.  If I copy the code into whatever object or class that needs the implicit Writes[Date] and above any object that needs a Date serialized, it works fine.  There has to be an easier way that I don't have to paste the code everywhere I need it and I can override every place Date is being serialized.

Comment: It does compile the code.  It just reverts to the default behavior of serializing the Date into milliseconds in whatever parts of the code where I don't have it placed properly.

Comment: That sounds like you just need to import the `Writes` implementation into the locations you need it (where you are currently copying the code to).

Comment: Yeah, you're right Shadowlands.  I just wish there were a way where I didn't have to explicitly import it wherever needed.  Whenever I forget to import it, my code will still compile and insert the unwanted default value which may not be immediately noticeable.  One might argue that good unit tests would expose the missing imports if there is no way in Scala to do what I want to do.